# How can you speed-up the compilation process on an SMP machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

What is the core working behind the speed-up compilation process on the SMP machine?

Answer (score 1):

Typically things like compilers and linkers are really bad at using multiple CPUs themselves.

However; often a large project will be broken up into many files that are compiled separately and then linked. For example; with 16 CPUs you could compile 16 separate files in parallel without much trouble (and then link all the object files after) and get the project built a lot faster (even though each instance of the compiler only uses one CPU itself).

For an added bonus; sometimes compilers will stall (e.g. have to wait for disk IO to read a source file or header or something). Using more processes (compiling more files in parallel) means that when one process/compiler stalls other processes may be able to continue, so there's less chance of a CPU being idle (doing nothing and not helping the project build faster).

In practice; this often ends up being controlled by whatever controls the building. For example, if you use `make` to figure out which pieces need to be compiled, then you might use `make -j=16` to tell the utility to try to run 16 jobs in parallel.